# Count rows of a particular day this week sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite.net

I would like to create a query which returns the number of rows for a particular day this week. For example, if `dayNumber = 1`, it should return the count of books where BookSaveTime is Monday. It should return the count for Tuesday if `dayNumber = 2`, and so on.

```
var week = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(((int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek+6)%7));
return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM Book WHERE BookSaveTime > ?;", week);
```

Currently, this query returns the number of books since the start of the week - but I am confused as to how to modify it such that it returns the count for a given specified day - eg, Monday or Tuesday.

```
public MyAppSQLiteDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteService>().GetConnection(DbFileName);
        database.CreateTable<Book>();

        CurrentState = "Database created";

    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        CurrentState = ex.Message;
    }
}

public int GetDailyCount(int dayNumber){
    var day = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(((int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek+6)%dayNumber));
    return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM Book WHERE BookSaveTime = ?;", day );
}
```

Book class:

```
public class Book: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private DateTime bookSaveTime;
    public DateTime BookSaveTime
    {
        get
        {
            return bookSaveTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (bookSaveTime != value)
            {
                bookSaveTime= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BookSaveTime");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use equals instead of greater than for starters. What is the datatype of the `bookEntryTime` column?

Comment: it also would be easier and helpful if you could show a little except of the table, especially whats inside the column ```bookEntryTime``` just to avoid any guesswork.

Comment: Please check my code and let me know does it serve your purpose properly or not. Best wishes . :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a specific weekday info your query should like below =>

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, cast (strftime('%w', BookSaveTime) as integer) AS WeekDay
FROM BOOK) T1
WHERE T1.WeekDay=1; --Weekday=1 is MONDAY
```

To Find the count of specific date use the query below

```
SELECT WeekDay,COUNT(*) AS WeekDayCount FROM
(SELECT *,strftime('%w',BookSaveTime) AS WeekDay
FROM BOOK) T1
GROUP BY T1.WeekDay
```

**Note:** You can add `WHERE BookSaveTime BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31'` inside the T1 to select data from particular date range. Demo Code in [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p7PUkka7UF6Yz7s84U4wAB/0).

Comment: Thank you @Linker. How can I convert this into an SQLite.NET ORM query? My attempt does not return any rows:  `return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, cast(strftime('%w', BookSaveTime) as integer) AS WeekDay FROM BOOK) T1 WHERE T1.WeekDay = 1;");`

Comment: I think `database.ExecuteScalar<int>` will return data for only one column so the code may be did not serve the purpose as you required. To get the enter table you can check think sample in the link => [SAMPLE SQLite C#](https://zetcode.com/csharp/sqlite/)